# Android file explorer crashes when viewing cordova .apk file

Tags: android, cordova

I built an app in Cordova, and after building it and copying the output apk file to my phone, whenever I open the android file explorer and go to the folder containing the .apk file, my file explorer crashes and closes.

I've tried deleting the output apk file and rebuilding it. And I've created a new cordova project and recreated the app. Nothing seems to fix the problem. The app did indeed run the first time I copied the apk file to my phone, but hasn't worked since.

I don't exactly know what code I'm supposed to share to help aid in the fixing of this problem, but I will edit the question and add the code that is needed.

So if anyone could maybe point out something I missed or something I should do, it would be much appreciated.

Also a side note. I do not intend on publishing my app on the PlayStore or any other public service.

Comment: which plugin are you using for file explorer and what is the error that you see?

Comment: @NidhinJoseph, I don't have plugins for my file explorer, and there's never an error. My file explorer just closes once I view the .apk file in its folder.

Comment: you will need to use logcat to inspect what the issue is.